# Refresh the cache programmatically in Magento 2 at window system

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I am looking for code that can refresh or flush the Magento2 cache via script.

It was so easy in Magento 1.x.

I am running Magento2 on WAMP server (window).

Comment: You can flush and cache using https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-clear-or-flush-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@denish,say by  using cmd you can clear cache. But ur issue at php command line

In order to run php client as command in window you  ***need to set php as environment*** available  [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

**After that you can run any of magento 2 cli command from cmd** like

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
           Or
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

*At going at your project location from  cmd*

Comment: like same what is the steps for magento 1.

Answer (score 26):

The below code programmatically flushes cache. It worked fine for me.

Case 1: Outside Magento

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


try{
    $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
    $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
    $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $msg = 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();die();
}
```

Case 2: Inside Magento

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}


$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

Comment: If one only needs to clean cache of a specific product https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636405/3733214

Answer (score 24):

Hardcoding the types is a **bad** idea. Instead you can use the same method used by the `cache:flush` and `cache:clean` commands. The cache manager class can also pull all the cache types for you, as done in the example below.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager
) {
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}

private function whereYouNeedToCleanCache()
{
    $this->cacheManager->flush($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());

    // or this
    $this->cacheManager->clean($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flush or refresh all the cache using following commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean   
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How to do it on window ?

Comment: @Arunendra, In `CLI` open magento root then enter to clear the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean` like this way to enter all commands. More info [click on this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands.html)

Comment: like same what is the steps for magento 1

Answer (score 1):

To add to denish's answer, you could write a little php script and place it into your magento root folder:

```
<?php
    $command = 'php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>
```

This will give you an output like:

```
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
translate
config_webservice
Flushed cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
translate
config_webservice
```

Please be sure you can actually excecute php from the command line, else this will be useless. 
For windows you have to make sure you have added the php.exe to your PATH in the Environment Variables. Please see http://willj.co/2012/10/run-wamp-php-windows-7-command-line/

Comment: it's showing nothing

Comment: For windows you have to make sure you have added the php.exe to your PATH in the Environment Variables. Please see http://willj.co/2012/10/run-wamp-php-windows-7-command-line/

Comment: If you are able to use shell_exec() for PHP, then your install is not secure.  This function should be disabled in a live environment.

Comment: This is the same as an sh script containing "php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush", except with added complexity and a requirement for non-safe configuration. Utter rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Define constructor – pass**

> Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface

and

> Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool

to your file’s constructor as defined below :-

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
```

**2. Now add following code to the method where you want clear/flush cache :-**

```
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

I hope this will useful for you.:)

Answer (score 0):

create a file named cacheflush.php and Upload  your Magento root folder like public_html of httdocs folder. then yoursite.com/cacheflush.php It will work perfectly. 
If you have no CLI mod in your hosting no problem... just use this code ..it will reduce your time .

```
<?php

        use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

        require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

        $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

        $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $k[0]='bin/magento';
        $k[1]='cache:flush'; // write your proper command like setup:upgrade,cache:enable etc...
        $_SERVER['argv']=$k;
        try {
            $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
            set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
            $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
            $application->run();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            while ($e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $e->getTraceAsString();
                echo "\n\n";
                $e = $e->getPrevious();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cacheManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager');
$cacheManager->flush($cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
```