# how to reindex magento 2 in wamp server windows8

Tags: magento2, magento-community, reindex

I tired to re-index magento 2.0.7 using CMD with command of php bin/magento indexer:reindex but i received `php` is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Please help me in this

Comment: Here is an free module https://ranasohel.me/2016/05/29/process-indexing-from-admin-in-magento2/

Answer (score 6):

Try This.
    open cmd and run it as administrator.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using windows then run this command in cmd

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:reindex

and if you want to reindex only one indexer then write following command:

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:reindex indexer_name.

where `indexer_name` can be found by typing following command :

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:info

Hope it helps

Comment: You can also simply CD to the magento folder in the wamp directory and run the command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have installed composer in your machine. So first you need to install composer to perform that operation.

Download composer by visiting [this link](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Comment: Hi, I hear about composer a lot, but i never tried and used it. Can we use Composer in windows 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

using cmd you can reindex cache. In order to run php client as command in window you  ***need to set php as environment*** available  [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/refresh-the-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2-at-window-system)

**After that you can run any of magento 2 cli command from cmd** like

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

[For more see Here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/refresh-the-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2-at-window-system)

Comment: I followed your steps, also i have to used path setup with one of my java developer. He sets path for me like how we did in java so that the command works proper.

Comment: Is it's working for you ?

Comment: Yes it is working fine

Comment: Please accept the answer for right answer it  will help other users.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add path of your php.exe file in you environment variable section.

You can add like below:

1. Right click on My Computer Icon and choose Property then advance settings.
2. Click on Environment Variable button
3. In a System variable section select "Path" variable and then click on edit button.
4. There you will find lot of path to .exe seperated by semicolon. you can also add your php.exe path there.

Restart command prompt to make it effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add PHP in environment variable. There are two ways to add environment variable, through MyComputer property and another is command prompt terminal.

I suggest you to use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) software for windows system it works like linux in windows system,

`setx PATH "%PATH%;[php bin path]"`

After configured PHP in environment variable, you reindex magento using

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```