# Reindexing Magento 2.0 on Xampp server

Tags: magento2

How can I Reindexing in Magento 2 on xampp server and My Oprating System is Windows 7.

Comment: It might help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/refresh-the-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2-at-window-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve below error:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Make sure your PHP path is added to your windows system's environment variable. After that you may able to run commands successfully.

Answer (score 1):

1.open your cmd and run:
2.change your root directory from //Magento root directory//
3.change location of drive

```
D:\xampp\php\php.exe D:\xampp\htdocs\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

in your case it would be:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_2.0\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below Command**

cd

The execute the below command

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: getting above error

Comment: you have to run this command from magento root cd <magento_root>         php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @H_Parekh Thats because you don't actually have PHP CLI installed. You need to install PHP CLI.

Comment: I am using "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_2.0>php bin/magento indexer:reindex"

Comment: how to install PHP CLI @Andre

Comment: you are using command Prompt Or gitbash ?

Comment: see the below screen its working fine http://screencast.com/t/uIAmRCzz

Comment: yes exactly i type that code in cmd but getting above error

Comment: Add C:\xampp\php to your PATH Environment Variable. Then Close The Command Prompt And Restart Again. Its important because if you didn't restart you command prompt then changes will not reflect.  PHP is not included in your PATH. Right click your My Computer, then Properties, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables and then find PATH variable, add your PHP installation dir there. Close your previously launched CMDs, re-launch it, it should work now.

Comment: did this worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Goto in your project root directory like :

> cd /your project folder path/

Then run the cmd :

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex