# One or more indexers are invalid .Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: magento2, cron, windows

On windows with xampp installed on c  . Did try all others answers didnt work for me.please answer step by step as im not too computer savy !thx !

Comment: Try : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/reindexing-magento-2-0-on-xampp-server/139308#139308

Comment: Did you tried my answer in given link ?

Comment: this question is very bad quality, and obviously have lots of duplicates... what we see here - moderator just useless... edits this question instead of just removing it and flag user....

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Command Prompt:
2. Change your directory to **Magento root** directory
3. For example **cd magento_2.0**
4. Run below Command:

   ```
   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_2.0\bin\magento indexer:reindex
   ```

**Note:** IF PHP path is alredy added to your windows system's environment variable you can directly run below command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Else you can add with [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)