# Magento 2 - Stock inventory qty cache problem

Tags: magento2, cache, stock, inventory

I can successfully updated the inventory qty in my custom module using the following lines of code. But the old value is still cached and displayed. I have already added `cacheable="false"` in the `layout xml` .

But it does not work. **How to flush the cache after I have updated the value? What is the proper way to do this?**

I now disable the full page cache for a workaround.

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
$stockItem->setData('qty',$qty-1);
$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```

Comment: Have u do indexing after stock update.

Comment: No. Do I need to run re-index every time I update the inventory qty? If so, I doubt that it works when I disabled the page cache.

Comment: Don't add cacheable=false on blocks because it's very bad, it won't let that page to be full page cached anymore. Don't use it. And if you have Indexer set to update by schedule than you need to add Magento 2 cron to crontab or whatever. MView will update cache and stock indexers for you (in cron). Or you can run the reindex command via cli ..

Comment: this may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131837/46716