# How to execute php command clear cache from front end page in magento2

Tags: magento2

To add to denish's answer, you could write a little php script and place it into your **magento root** folder:

```
$command = 'php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush';
echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
```

This code place to which folder and what file in root directory, When I run my page in frontend : https://www.atomicgolf.shop/contact-list

How could I do for this?

Comment: If i understand right you want to clear the cache when someone visits a front end page? Cache is what is keeping your website fast.

Comment: yes, I want clear cache by this command in side code. But It has 3 ways to clear. I have done with it inside my code. This link : URL : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/refresh-the-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2-at-window-system

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    /* Code to clean cache [ php bin/magento:cache:clean ] */
        try{
            $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
            $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
            $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
            }
            foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
                $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $msg = 'Error during cache clean: '.$e->getMessage();die();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE and Please elaborate your answer