# Clearing Full Page Caching on product stock change Magento2 custom product listing page

Tags: magento2, product-list, caching

I want to clear full page caching on my custom product listing page in my module if any product get out of stock. Actually I need to show "out of stock" label on the products that are not in stock but that is not happening due to full page caching and I cannot turn caching off also as it would slow down my page.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear "Block HTML Output", "Collections Data" and "Page Cache".
https://goo.gl/w5gaXB

Comment: actually I want to do it programmatically not manually...if anyone could throw some light on cache tags and cache validation key etc

Comment: you did not specify this in the question, but I edited your question.

Comment: can anyone help me in this

Comment: what about https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131837/46716 ?