# Magento 2: Disable and enable payment method programmatically

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment-methods, plugin

I want to place order programmatically. I do not have COD enable when I placed the order programmatically so can it be possible that I can enable the COD before order place and disable COD after Order place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Object Manager is not proper way but as i know this may be write answer.
it helps you.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('payment/cashondelivery/active');
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface')->save('payment/cashondelivery/active', 1);
/*
your code
*/
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface')->save('payment/cashondelivery/active', 0);
```

Refresh Cache.

See below link

[Refresh the cache programmatically in Magento 2 at window system](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/refresh-the-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2-at-window-system#answer-131837)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config` object.

Like Following Code

```
$this->resourceConfig->saveConfig('payment/cashondelivery/active', '1', 'default', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES);
```

after complition order you need to set to `0`

It will help you